# UI Bootstrap Popover: change width

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the popovers from UI Bootstrap in AngularJS:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

```
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" popover="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta libero tincidunt, malesuada tellus vitae, dapibus ex. Ut tristique tristique eros." popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right"></i>
```

It gives me a popover like this:

[image]

How can I style change the width of this popover?

Comment: angular-ui bootstrap directive having directive binding variable "**uib-tooltip-classes**" ,The class name which passed to **uib-tooltip-classes** will appened to your popup parent container when its open.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve it by overriding popover-content class:

```
.popover-content {
width: 200px;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can check this in Chrome:
- press F12
- select the magnifier
- click on the element to inspect
- modify its style
[image]

Comment: In my experience, when you change this property in the devtools, it will properly change. But when it's changed in the .css file associated with my angular project, the change is ignored.

Answer (score 32):

From the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) you can use the

> `popover-class` attribute -  Custom class to be applied to the popover

```
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" popover-class="increase-popover-width" popover="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta libero tincidunt, malesuada tellus vitae, dapibus ex. Ut tristique tristique eros." popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right"></i>
```

In your style sheet

```
.increase-popover-width {
   max-width: 400px;
}
```

The reason for setting `max-width` instead of `width` is that bootstrap has `popover-max-width` set as **276px**.

[github bootstrap code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L710)

Comment: popover-class doesn't work for me but I have very old bootsrap ui version (0.12.1) and this is the reason. I should update it to at least 0.13.0 because as documentation states from this version popover-class is respected: [https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: What is more bootstrap ui 0.13.x needs angular 1.3.x

Answer (score 9):

Another solution if you have very wide popovers is to allow them to autosize

Just set your css to be like this

```
.popover {
    max-width: 800px; /* optional max width */
    width: intrinsic; /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
    width: -moz-max-content; /* Firefox/Gecko */
    width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me the following worked

```
.popover {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

This actually changed the size of the popover white container.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the **popover-append-to-body** attribute of the popover component?

Answer (score 0):

The width can be changed easily by overriding the `.popover`:

```
.popover {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .popover {
        width: 500px;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

In my case both parameters was important and took effect