# Increase the width of the popover

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to show a popover on Mouse over. 
 The problem I am having is to increase the size of the popover box.

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q1PjNY3OadhwBTThCiCz?p=preview)

I tried to adjust the width using css as shown below :

```
    .popover-inner {
width: 400px;
}
 .popover-content {
width: 500px;
}
```

but didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI Bootstrap Popover: change width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005345/ui-bootstrap-popover-change-width)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the width of Bootstrap popover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your code and your problem, the problem is you are trying to edit an element whithout the correct selector (`.popover`). And when you try to edit the correct selector it has an `max-width property`. So it doesn't work. But is enough with

```
   .popover {
     max-width: 500px;
   }
```

That is all.

But I try your plnkr and find you are using modals classes in the code. That is a mistake. Because it's not the grammar or use of the css. So I add new css classes:

```
.popover-content > .header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; 
}
 .popover-content > .body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

And change the `popover.html` to:

```
<div class="header">
   <b>How is this amount calculated?</b>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <h4>PQ * A% * CR AVG </h4>
  <br />
  PQ - Pre-Qualified based on your historical data <br />
  A% - Approval percentage <br />
  CR AVG - (Historical Credits Earned) / (Total Certificates)
</div>
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
```

You can check my plnkr fork:https://plnkr.co/edit/p4dr2XMzQqw8R6RYOsMo?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.popover-inner {
   width: 500px !important;
   max-width:500px !important;
}
.popover {
   width: 500px !important;
   max-width:500px !important;
}
```

This takes advantage of the [!important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) to apply the style.

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.

Comment: Every time you use an !important in css code. God kills a cat. :( Please don't use !important if it's not necessary.

Comment: @JoséLezama Nothing wrong with using !important in a case where you don't own the style sheet IMO. If it was his own stylesheet, then no need for !important.

Comment: In fact, `!important` has its own time as you say. It's true! And as you say normally came with the need of overwrite an third-party css. But in this case it was not necessary! As you can look with the code before suggested by me, or in the other response suggested in the comments of the question. So, If you can do without `!important` it was an unnecessary use of `important` So, a cat had die. :( If you want you can read: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ @HanletEscaño