# angularJS popover, how to use a template?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a popover (bootstrap v3.3.7) in my angularJs app,
I can successfully add a popover like this:

```
<div uib-popover="Hello" popover-title="Test" popover-placement="bottom-left" popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"></div>
```

this works perfectly, now how can I do something like I did with bootstrap modals, having an external htm file as template where I can put all the data I wanna show in the popover?

I tried creating a htm page with some DIVs, and link it in the popover like this:

```
 popover-template="'Views/Popovers/myPopoverTemplate.htm'"
```

but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong? thank you

[image: popover]

external template:

```
<div class="testbox">
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>test header</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>test body</span>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Footer - Buttons go here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css for the template:

```
.testbox {
background: #fff;
color: #000;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 200px;
min-width: 500px;
position: absolute;
```

}

Comment: since it's `ui`, have you tried using `uib-popover-template` instead?

Comment: ok that works! but there is a small issue, it opens the content in the external file, but it opens 2 popovers, one is the small one from popover, and next to it, it opens a square with the content of the external html file!

How can I put my content INSIDE the popover window (the small one with the arrow-like top edge that you see in the picture?)

added the picture in my original post

Comment: can you show what that template looks like? could be some CSS issues

Comment: updated my first post with css and markup for external file

Comment: `position: absolute;` breaks it

Comment: thank you, it was that, but I see that putting 
  `  min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 500px;` also makes the template go outside the popover borders, is there a way to define a minimum size of the popover, and then if the content is bigger it will get bigger, that s ok, but even if the content is not much I would like to have a fixed minimum size!

Comment: Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AOpyucm6SschebmkXt1k?p=preview) you can play with. You would need to adjust the [popup width as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005345/ui-bootstrap-popover-change-width) for it to match your template

Comment: slight typo, I think you need your `.popover` class to have **min**-width, which you can remove from `.testbox` class

Comment: thank you!! added this :  `popover-class="popoverCustomSize"`  and then made a custom class in css and the min-width and height work perfectly!! thank you again! if you post it in a new post I ll mark it as correct answer! have a wonderful day